# Riak and time-sorted records

Tags: riak

I'd like to sort some records, stored in riak, by a function of the each record's score and "age" (current time - creation date).  **What is the best way do do a "time-sensitive" query in riak?**  Thus far, the options I'm aware of are:

- Realtime mapreduce - Do the entire calculation in a mapreduce job, at query-time
- ETL job - Periodically do the query in a background job, and store the result back into riak
- Punt it to the app layer - Don't sort at all using riak, and instead use an application-level layer to sort and cache the records.

Mapreduce seems the best on paper, however, I've read mixed-reports about the real-world latency of riak mapreduce.

Answer (score 1):

MapReduce is a quite expensive operation and not recommended as a real-time querying tool. It works best when run over a limited set of data in batch mode where the number of concurrent mapreduce jobs can be controlled, and I would therefore not recommend the first option.

Having a process periodically process/aggregate data for a specific time slice as described in the second option could work and allow efficient access to the prepared data through direct key access. The aggregation process could, if you are using leveldb, be based around a secondary index holding a timestamp. One downside could however be that newly inserted records may not show up in the results immediately, which may or may not be a problem in your scenario.

If you need the computed records to be accurate and will perform a significant number of these queries, you may be better off updating the computed summary records as part of the writing and updating process.

In general it is a good idea to make sure that you can get the data you need as efficiently as possibly, preferably through direct key access, and then perform filtering of data that is not required as well as sorting and aggregation on the application side.